# Using aggregate functions on alias column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following relations:

```
    movies(MovieCode(pk), Title, Rating, Length) //pk=primary key
    theaters(TheaterCode(pk), Name, Address, Phone)
    movies2theaters(MovieCode, TheaterCode, MovieTime)
```

Now I want to list the average length of movies played at a particular theater and I'm writing below query.

```
select
  avg(m.length) as 'Average Length'
from 
  movies m,
  theaters t,
  movies2theaters mt
where
  m.moviecode = mt.moviecode
  AND t.theatercode = mt.theatercode
  AND t.name = 'XYZ';
```

And I'm getting below output:

```
     --------------
    |Average Length|
    ----------------
    |    Null      |
    ----------------
```

Null is definitely not the output. I'm not sure how we can use aggregate functions on an alias column to get the correct output. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The query appears basically correct. Remove the aggregate `AVG()` and just `SELECT Length....` with that set of joins. Do you get results? If not, the joins are incorrect or `t.Name` contains no values `'XYZ'`.

Comment: Consider posting a small sample of rows from each table.

Comment: Please stop using implicit (comma separated) joins, and switch to explicit `join` syntax.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski As you said, I tried 'select length' instead of m.length and I'm getting 'empty set' as an output. I also double checked the t.name and I'm writing it correctly (checked letter by letter). Also checked the join condition again. But when I check in database, there is t.name present and movies were played at this particular theater.

Comment: provide a test data set please http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Then you either got the join wrong or the data from the various tables do not fully match.

Comment: No theaters match that name.

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query), and note that we stopped joining tables this way circa 1992!

Comment: @Strawberry I don't know who you are referring to with 'we', but I've noticed it's still used despairingly often.

Comment: @HoneyBadger But not, so far as I am aware, in any of your esteemed answers!